# Selenium webdriver verifying the text displayed in one row

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, word-wrap

I encountered a problem when trying to check if some text on a page is displayed in one row,
I mean the html does not contain br tag, but because of resolution / font size  - the text is wrapped to a second row. Is there a way to know it with selenium?

Comment: I have edited the question, tagging it rephrasing it slightly to make it clearer that it is asking about word wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a great solution, but might give you some ideas.  We have text that is supposed to wrap to a second line when the browser width narrows to a certain point.  I started full width `driver.manage().window().maximize();` and got the height and width of the element containing the text.  Then I set the browser window to a smaller size  `driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width, height));` and got the height and width of the same element again, and then could verify that the new height is roughly double the previous height, and the width is less, indicating it may be wrapped.  I suppose the element height could grow but the text would not wrap (just be cut off), but this is the best I could think of.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: Yes

Long answer:

Suppose we have this element on webpage:

```
<span id="longtext">Very very long long text yada yada blah blah blah</span>
```

Then

```
driver.findElement(By.id("longtext")).getText()
```

will return you that text inside the span. And as far as I know it should not matter how is it wrapped in the page.

But if you have something like this:

```
<span id="longtext">Longer text which is <span id="warning">boringly</span> long</span>
```

Then getting text of this will be little bit harder I suppose.

But generally, displaying on the page should not matter and in most cases the `getText()` method from `WebDriver` class should return you the whole thing.

*Note* the `driver` variable in above example is expected healthy and living instance of `WebDriver` class. I am using Java in my own scripts, so the pseudocode is Java-based Webdriver example

Comment: Thanks alot, but I understand from your answer that the answer is still no - there is not a way to know this, because the gettext() return only the text Without consider how is it wrapped in the page.

Comment: @PavelJanicek Yes, that's what he asked.

Comment: Downgraded this answer because it purports to answer the question and then spends 90% of the answer NOT answering the actual question at hand.